# python regular expression Variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to use a lookup table to replace values in a text file

The format of the lookup table is like

```
Search             Replace
Unit Of Measure    Unit of Measure
Bill Of Material   Bill of Material
Reference Item     Reference Material Number
```

I am using `re.sub(Search, Replace, File)`

I need to do something like `(r'\b Unit Of Measure\b', Replace, File)` for every iteration.

I am not able to put these tags into a variable.

Could you please help?

Below is the code

```
import re
f1 = open('C:\Scripts\FNR\SearchReplacekey.txt','r')
f = open("C:\Scripts\FNR\log.txt",'a')
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
f.close()
for line in f1:
    fields = line.split('|')
    a = fields[0]
    Srch = fields[1]
    Repl = fields[2]
    f = open("C:\Scripts\FNR\Output.txt",'r')
    filedata = f.read()
    check = re.search(Srch,filedata)
    f.close()

    if check == -1:

        f = open("C:\Scripts\FNR\log.txt",'a')
        newdata = a + ' ' + Srch + ' ' + Repl
        f.write(newdata + "\n")
        f.close()
    else:

        # the problem is here I need to force Srch to match exact word
        newdata = re.sub(Srch,Repl,filedata)

        f = open("C:\Scripts\FNR\Output.txt",'w')
        f.write(newdata)
        f.close()
```

Thanks,
Kowsik

Comment: Could you provide some more code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543559/python-regex-match-and-replace

Comment: Code has been added

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but could it be that:

```
searchs = ["Unit Of Measure", "Bill Of Material"]
for s in searchs:
  re.sub(s, Replace, File)
```

Comment: I am not asking that
For example.
Consider the below text  

line1 .'a Unit Of Measure
line2 . BaseUnit Of Measure'

I need to replace only line1 and not line 2 

I know for this we need to use re.sub(r'\b Unit Of Measure\b', Replace, File)

But I am getting the search string from a variable which is coming from a different file.
My question is what changes do i need to make so the variable can  can be used to search for the exact word

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>searchPattern = "Unit Of Measure"
>>>replacePatter = "Unit of Measure"
>>>sampleString = "not Unit Of measure, but Unit Of Measure and not Unit Of"
>>>re.sub(searchPattern,replacePatter, sampleString)
'not Unit Of measure, but Unit of Measure and not Unit Of'
```

Maybe I am missing something here, but if you enclose the patterns in quotes this seems to work well enough.

Comment: this is coming from a file so i wont be able to edit anything, plus i am trying to use exact match , which will work only with r('\bSearchString\b'),I am not able to add this to the search string as it comes from a file.